# NHibernate produce System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to optimize two requests to DB into one like this:

```
    var subQuery = Session
        .Query<IProfile>()
        .Where(profile => accountIds.Contains(profile.AccountId))
        .GroupBy(profile => profile.AccountId)
        .Select(kv => kv.Max(profile => profile.Id));
        //.ToList();

    var outQuery = Session
        .Query<IProfile>()
        .Where(profile => subQuery.Contains(profile.Id))
        .Fetch(profile => profile.User)
        .Fetch(profile => profile.Email);

    var result = outQuery.ToList();
```

but this produse an System.ArgumentException

but if it is two separate requests to DB like this

```
    var subQuery = Session
        .Query<IProfile>()
        .Where(profile => accountIds.Contains(profile.AccountId))
        .GroupBy(profile => profile.AccountId)
        .Select(kv => kv.Max(profile => profile.Id))
        .ToList();
```

everything work properly.

More info about exception:

> 'System.Nullable1[System.Int64]' cannot be used as the data type for a
>   sequence with an ItemExpression of type
>   'System.Nullable1[System.Int64]'. Parameter name: dataType
>
> at
>   Remotion.Linq.Clauses.StreamedData.StreamedSequenceInfo.AdjustDataType(Type
>   dataType) at Remotion.Linq.QueryModel.GetOutputDataInfo() at
>   Remotion.Linq.QueryModel.GetResultType() at
>   NHibernate.Linq.NestedSelects.NestedSelectRewriter.ProcessSubquery(ISessionFactory
>   sessionFactory, ICollection1 elementExpression, QueryModel queryModel,
>   Expression group, QueryModel subQueryModel)    at
>   NHibernate.Linq.NestedSelects.NestedSelectRewriter.ProcessExpression(QueryModel
>   queryModel, ISessionFactory sessionFactory, Expression expression,
>   List1 elementExpression, ParameterExpression group) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.NestedSelects.NestedSelectRewriter.ReWrite(QueryModel
>   queryModel, ISessionFactory sessionFactory) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel
>   queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitSubQueryExpression(SubQueryExpression
>   expression) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression
>   expression) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   expression, VisitorParameters parameters) at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.VisitWhereClause(WhereClause
>   whereClause, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index) at
>   Remotion.Linq.Clauses.WhereClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor,
>   QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index) at
>   Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitBodyClauses(ObservableCollection1
>   bodyClauses, QueryModel queryModel)    at
>   Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel
>   queryModel)    at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.Visit()
>   at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel
>   queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)    at
>   NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor
>   sessionFactory, Boolean filter)    at
>   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary2
>   filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) at
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan.CreateTranslators(IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary2
>   enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)    at
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryExpressionPlan..ctor(IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary2 enabledFilters,
>   ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) at
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary2 enabledFilters)    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression, Boolean shallow)    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression
>   queryExpression)    at
>   NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression
>   expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)    at
>   NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
>   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase1.GetEnumerator() at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection) at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to rewrite the two queries combined like this:

```
Session.Query<IProfile>()
    .Where(profile => 
        Session.Query<IProfile>()
           .Where(pf => accountIds.Contains(pf.AccountId))
           .GroupBy(pf => pf.AccountId)
           .Select(kv => kv.Max(pf => pf.Id)) // subQuery
           .Any(id => profile.Id == id)) // outQuery
    .Fetch(profile => profile.User)
    .Fetch(profile => profile.Email);
```

Comment: hm, I understand. I suppose `AccountId` or `Profile Id` are nullable, try a similar approach like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023010/nhibernate-linq-system-nullable-throws-argumentexception-the-value-is-not-ty

Comment: I thought about this before and tryed to do like this:
 var subQuery = Session
  .Query<IProfile>()
  .Where(profile => accountIds.Contains(profile.AccountId))
  .GroupBy(profile => profile.AccountId)
  .Select(kv => kv.Max(profile => profile.Id.Value));
 var outQuery = Session
  .Query<IProfile>()
  .Where(profile => subQuery.Contains(profile.Id.Value))
...
error was something like (same but without nullable):
'[System.Int64]' cannot be used as the data type for a sequence with an ItemExpression of type '[System.Int64]'.

And AccountId is not nullable